# Using \pgfplotsinvokeforeach in foreach loop

Tags: loops, foreach

I am trying to run a `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` loop in a `\foreach` loop to plot the variables 
var1_roll1 - var1_roll10 in one plot and var2_roll1 - var2_roll10  in another. 
Both loops work fine individually but a combination of both gives the following error:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition
>   of \pgffor@body.

Can anyone help? Here is the Code. Thanks!

```
\begin{figure}    
\foreach \dt in {1,2} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[]
           \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,2,...,10} { 
            \addplot[]  table[x=x,y=var\dt_roll#1] {../plot/test.txt};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `\pgfplotstableinvokeforeach` in this case, simply nesting two ordinary `\foreach` loops works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
x var1_roll1 var1_roll2 var2_roll1 var2_roll2
1 10 11 20 21
2 10 11 20 21
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach\dt in {1,2}{
    \foreach\roll in {1,2}{
        \addplot table [y=var\dt_roll\roll]{\datatable};
    }
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My Intention was to have two axis environments but this is also possible with your suggestion by placing the first \foreach before \begin{åxis} . Thanks